# Ensure a base64 encoded string never includes a nonalphanumerical character

Tags: base64

Is there anyway to ensure that a base64 encoded string never includes a non-alphanumerical character?

For example, if I have a long string that I encode, is there something I can prepend or append to it that will ensure that when encoded with base64 will only include letters and numbers in the encoded string? Something like this:

String: `192.168.1.1`

Encoded: `MTkyLjE2OC4xLjE=` <- I want to 'get rid' of the equal sign.

I tried appending `}` at the end of the string (new string is now `192.168.1.1}`), and this worked (new encoded string: `MTkyLjE2OC4xLjF9`), but is there a method of ensuring every combination works?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rtrim() the equals signs away, which is what most people do.

but as for your question: when length of string / 3 is a whole number. So:

```
$pad = strlen($str) % 3; if($pad) { $str .= str_repeat(' ', $pad); }
```

but yeah, the parser will add the equals signs back in automatically just like that, to a multiple of 4, when you pass the string back in - so you dont need to keep them.

Comment: Your code is wrong if $str = AAA $pad = 0 no problem but , $str=AAAA $pad=1 so it will repeat space once while it should do it twice to avoid equal sign, $str=AAAAA $pad=2 same problem will repeat two rather than once. So it should be                                         $pad = strlen($string)%3;
   if($pad == 1){
      $string.= str_repeat('Q',2);
   }elseif($pad == 2){
      $string.= str_repeat('Q',1);
   }else {
      $pad='0';                                                       }

Answer (score 1):

It's about the length. The = sign is padding to make the output a multiple of 4 base64 characters. 3 characters translate to 4 base64 characters, so you just need to make your input string a multiple of 3 characters in length somehow. In your case:

```
192.168.1.1 - 11 characters long, base64 ends with =
192.168.1.1$ - 12 characters long, base64 doesn't end with =
```

Choose a padding character you can easily remove.

The other alternative is to strip the = from the output, then make sure you append = signs to make a multiple of 4 characters before you try to base64 decode...

Comment: Interesting. So I would have to do something like a ternary on the string before returning it (if I use a function to produce the encoded string) to ensure that it doesn't end with a non-alphanumerical.

Comment: This is part of the definition of `base64`.  The encoding also uses a number of nonalphanumeric characters in order to be able to accommodate 64 bits (the encoded string can contain `/` or `+` too).  If this is unacceptable, you should be looking for an alternative to `base64` rather than hack it.  (There is a spec called base62 which might be more suitable for you.)  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64